# Как скомпилировать программу находясь на каталог выше go.mod?

Tags: golang, компиляция, path, build

У меня есть программа которая компилирует другие программы:
compiler.go:

```go
package main

import (
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "projects/helloword/main.go")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    cmd.Run()
}
```

Всё дерево каталогов выглядит так:

```
.
├── compiler <- Исполняемый файл который билдит проект ниже.
└── projects
    └── helloword
        ├── go.mod
        ├── hi
        │   └── hi.go
        └── main.go
```

Проблема в том что насколько я понял компилятор не видит go.mod так как `go build` запускается на каталог выше go.mod.

```
projects/helloword/main.go:3:8: no required module provides package github.com/c0caina/helloword/hi: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules'
```

Как скомпилировать проект из другой программы?
Я не могу опустить `compiler` на уровень ниже что бы он находился в одной папке с go.mod.
Есть какие то другие способы скомпилировать?
Например вызвать `exec.Command` не в том же месте где лежит исполняемый файл а в каталоге `helloword`. Или может есть какой то другой способ об котором я не догадываюсь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в `cmd` есть специальное поле `Dir`, отвечающее за рабочую директорию. можно ее определить, задать из какой директории будет выполняться программа.

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "build", "projects/helloword/main.go")
cmd.Dir = "/path/to/dir/"
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Run()
```